# Javascript window not opening when Bootstrap script or jqueries are on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page I'm trying to make responsive using Bootstrap. It's our part tables and it mostly works, but I'm having some issues with some Javascript code. Hopefully I entered the code below correctly into this web site. Here's the page I'm having issues with:

https://www.ironwoodelectronics.com/catalog/Content/Templates/BrowsePartGridResponsive.cfm?StartRow=1&cPart=SG-BGA-6000&PartNumber=sg-bga-6000&pincount=&Pinsearch=false&leadPitch=&Manufacturer=0&Man_IC=0&Functions=0&BODYSIZE=&ARRAYSIZE=

If you click the Log in to see Pricing button, it's supposed to come up with a window to enter an email and country. Once you do that and click submit, it reloads this page and shows the price. But for some reason, I'm not able to get the window to open when the link is clicked. There is some conflict with some Javascript with Bootstrap. I know this because I had everything working until I added a few scripts for Bootstrap such as to get the drop down menus working with Bootstrap. This is the original page so you can see how it should work before any bootstrap scripts or jqueries were added:

https://www.ironwoodelectronics.com/catalog/Content/Templates/BrowsePartGrid.cfm?StartRow=1&cPart=SG-BGA-6000&PartNumber=sg-bga-6000&pincount=&Pinsearch=false&leadPitch=&Manufacturer=0&Man_IC=0&Functions=0&BODYSIZE=&ARRAYSIZE=

I was thinking I could just create a modal window with Bootstrap, but then I wasn't sure how to reload the page to get the price to show up with Javascript. Here's some of the Javascript that makes this work below.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="#application.SecureBaseURL#/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="#application.SecureBaseURL#/js/thickbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pricingLogin() {
tb_show('','#application.SecureBaseURL#/catalog/Content/Templates/incPricingLogin.cfm?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=200&width=400');
    }

    function reloadPartsGrid() {
         location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

Here's the code for the page with the form in the little window. It's created with ColdFusion

```
<cfparam name="Close_Window" default="false">
<cfparam name="distributorID" default="0">
<cfsetting showdebugoutput="no">

<cfquery name="getDistributor"
  datasource="#application.DataSource#"
  cachedwithin="#CreateTimeSpan(1,0,0,0)#">
    SELECT *
    FROM Distributor
    Order By DisplayID
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>

<script type="text/javascript" src="#application.SecureBaseURL#/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    closeWindow = function() {
        self.parent.reloadPartsGrid();
        self.parent.tb_remove();
    }

    isValidEmailAddress = function(emailAddress) {
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
        return pattern.test(emailAddress);
    }

    validate = function() {
        if($("##distributorID").val() == '0') {
            alert("Please select your country");
            return false;
        }
        if(!isValidEmailAddress($("##email").val())) { 
            alert("Please enter a valid email address");
            return false;
        }

        if(!this.form.Opt_In_Email.checked)
        {
          alert('You must agree to the terms first.');
          return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
</script>

<cfif distributorID GT 0>
    <cfquery name="getUser" datasource="#application.DataSource#">
        SELECT *
        FROM SC_Customers
        WHERE Email = '#Email#'
    </cfquery>

    <cfif getUser.RecordCount>
        <cfquery name="updateUser" datasource="#application.DataSource#">
            UPDATE SC_Customers
            SET DistributorID = '#DistributorID#',
                Opt_In_Email = '#Opt_In_Email#'
            WHERE Email = '#Email#'
        </cfquery>
    <cfelse>
        <cfquery name="updateUser" datasource="#application.DataSource#">
            INSERT INTO SC_Customers
                (Email, DistributorID, Opt_In_Email)
            Values
                ('#Email#', '#DistributorID#', '#Opt_In_Email#')
        </cfquery>
    </cfif>



    <cfset session.distributorID = distributorID>

    <script>
        closeWindow();
    </script>

<cfelse>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: arial;
        }
    </style>

    <cfset session.distributorID = 0>
    <form onsubmit="return validate()">
    <table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="100%"><strong>Please complete the form
          below to see pricing.</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="distributorID">Your Country:</label></td>
        <td>
            <select id="distributorID" name="distributorID">
                <option value="0">Select Country</option>
                <cfloop query="getDistributor">
                    <option value="#ID#">#Country_Name#</option>
                </cfloop>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="email">Email Address:</label></td>
        <td>
            <input type="Text" id="email" name="email" value="">
        </td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
        <td colspan="100%"><input type="checkbox" value="1"
          name="Opt_In_Email"> <font size="-2">Opt-in to receive
          Ironwood Electronics Communications via E-mail. Please
          read our <a href="https://www.ironwoodelectronics.com/catalog/Content/Drawings/Privacy_Policy.pdf"
            title="Privacy Policy" target="new">Privacy Policy</a>.</font>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="100%" align="center">
            <input type="Submit" name="Submit" onclick="if(!this.form.Opt_In_Email.checked){alert('You must agree to Opt-in to receive Ironwood Electronics Communications via E-mail first.');return false}"
              value="Submit">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="Button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel"
              onclick="closeWindow();">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>    
    </form>
</cfif>

</cfoutput>
```

This is the login button to pop up the window:

```
<div><a href="javascript:pricingLogin();" role="button"
  class="btn green_button green_background">Log in to see pricing</a></div>
```

How can I get this javascript window to open up so a user can enter their info., the page gets reloaded, and the price displays?

Thanks for anyone's help.

Andy

Comment: I don't see Bootstrap being used at all. Do you still want to know how to use a responsive Bootstrap modal on this page?

Comment: There's an error in the console: `TypeError: jQuery.browser is undefined`. That feature was [removed in jQuery 1.9](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/) (you are including multiple versions: 1.3.2, 1.9.1 and 1.11).

Comment: Which version should I use? I probably downloaded Bootstrap's javascript or jQuery a few different times and just kept each version in the page, but when I remove these one at a time, it still doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Your old dependencies (thickbox.js) rely on the `$.browser` functionality. But bootstrap *probably* requires a newer version. That functionality is available in the  jQuery.migrate plugin. If you need to go > 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get my login button working. I needed to move the scripts and Jquery up higher on the page for the bootstrap menus to work. Then further down the page is where the login button javascript needed to be in order for the login button to work. Thanks for everyone's help!